# Electron setProxy() and fromPartition() not working

Tags: node.js, proxy, electron

I am trying to build a program where each new BrowserWindow has its own proxy to go with it. The issue is that whenever I use window.webContents.session.setProxy, every window gets the same proxy; I want them to all be different.

I know that I need to use partitions to create a new session each time, I just haven't figured out how to do it.

Whenever I try creating a new partition, the proxy does not work. I haven't found any examples of this being done before, but I am confident that it is possible.

Reference: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington Not sure what the issue was but it was fixed by updating to the latest version of electron.